# My program crashes every time i call class function from another class C++

Tags: c++

When running the program the program crashes. The error is in createNewBook() function in Administrator class (bk->create_Newbook();). I tried many ways to call the create_Newbook() function of the Book class from the Administrator class but the program always crashes.

```
class Book{
private:
    char bookName[50],bookAuthor[50];
public:
    void create_Newbook()
    {
    cout<<"\nNEW BOOK ENTRY...\n";
    cout<<"\n\nEnter The Name of The Book:";
    cin>>bookName;
    cout<<"\n\nEnter The Author's Name:";
    cin>>bookAuthor;
    cout<<"\n\n\nBook Created..";
    }
```

};

```
class Administrator{
private:
    Book *bk;
public:
    void admin_menu();
    void displayStudent(){cout << "Access Student file....." ;}
    void displayStaff() {cout << "Access Staff file....." ;}
    void displayOutsider() {cout << "Access Outsider file....." ;}
    void deleteStudent() {cout << "Access to delete student data.....";}
    void deleteStaff() {cout << "Access to delete staff data.....";}
    void deleteOutsider() {cout << "Access to delete outsider data.....";}
    void createNewBook();
    void displayAllbook() {cout << "Access the file display ALL books.....";}
```

};

```
void Administrator::createNewBook() {
char choice;
newBook.open("book.data",ios::out|ios::app);
do
{
    bk->create_Newbook();
    newBook.write((char*)&bk,sizeof(Book));
    cout<<"\n\nDo you want to add more record..(y/n?)";
    cin>>choice;
}while(choice=='y'||choice=='Y');
   newBook.close();
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: Is `bk` allocated? ps: use `std::string`

Comment: `(char*)&bk` this looks suspicios and most probably wrong, but without [mcve] it is impossible to say for sure

Comment: Rather than `CreateNewThisOrThat` functions, it's better to use constructors.

Comment: `(char *)&bk`..  Since `bk` is already a pointer, what is accomplished by writing the address of a pointer?  That probably should be `(char *)bk`.,

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of issues with this piece of code.

First:

`newBook.open("book.data", ios::out | ios::app);`

This line uses an object called newBook, which hasn't been created or initialized anywhere.

Second:

`bk->create_Newbook();`

You haven't initialized `bk` anywhere. If it's a null pointer, then your program will crash. You're missing constructors and destructors. At some point in your code, you would need to create the object: E.g.

`bk = new Book()`

Comment: How can you say if `bk` was initialized or not?

Comment: @Slava because it's a private variable and none of his functions initialize it

Comment: Do you see implementation of all members? How?

Comment: His functions are written in the class itself. That's how.

Comment: `admin_menu()` is not. And his code is not complete, for example `newBook` which is most probably `std::ofstream` is not declared anywhere. You should wait before you can answer properly rather than guessing.

Comment: You are very likely correct, but `new book`isn't a good answer. Not requiring a dynamic `bk` is.

Comment: Well, considering he didn't say "I initialize bk in admin_menu()", people answering the question have to assume otherwise. This is best-guess theory based on the question at hand, not speculation as to whether or not the user was capable of anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::ios;
using std::fstream;

class Book{
private:
    char bookName[50],bookAuthor[50];
public:
    void create_Newbook()
    {
    cout << "\nNEW BOOK ENTRY...\n";
    cout << "\n\nEnter The Name of The Book:";
    cin >> bookName;
    cout << "\n\nEnter The Author's Name:";
    cin >> bookAuthor;
    cout << "\n\n\nBook Created..";
    }

}; 

class Administrator{
private:
    Book *bk;
public:
    void admin_menu();
    void displayStudent(){cout << "Access Student file....." ;}
    void displayStaff() {cout << "Access Staff file....." ;}
    void displayOutsider() {cout << "Access Outsider file....." ;}
    void deleteStudent() {cout << "Access to delete student data.....";}
    void deleteStaff() {cout << "Access to delete staff data.....";}
    void deleteOutsider() {cout << "Access to delete outsider data.....";}
    void createNewBook();
    void displayAllbook() {cout << "Access the file display ALL books.....";}

};

void Administrator::createNewBook() {
char choice;
fstream newBook; //just create newBook
newBook.open("book.data",ios::out|ios::app);
do
{
    bk->create_Newbook(); //this will work. No need to create a new Book varible to call a public function
    newBook.write((char*)&bk,sizeof(Book));
    cout << "\n\nDo you want to add more record..(y/n?)";
    cin >> choice;
}while(choice=='y'||choice=='Y');
   newBook.close();

}

int main()
{

    Administrator var_a;

    var_a.createNewBook();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
 NEW BOOK ENTRY...


 Enter The Name of The Book:abcd


 Enter The Author's Name:efgh



 Book Created..
```

It would have been better if you had constructors

Comment: where is `bk` initialized?

Comment: You don't need to initialize bk. As 'Book *bk' is already used, one can now use bk->create_NewBook(). Look at this function. It already assigns a value to the private variables of bk. So this works.

Comment: _You don't need to initialize bk._  This is incorrect. With an uninitialized pointer, the behavior of the program is "undefined", which means that anything can happen.  For you, the program runs, but for the OP, the program does not run.  You might find this article helpful: https://www.nayuki.io/page/undefined-behavior-in-c-and-cplusplus-programs

Comment: Sorry! A big mistake on my side. Thanks for that. I only used "Must Initialize" rule to pointers of built in data types and containers. Never had any issues using uninitialized pointers for classes.

Comment: @GLaDOS -- `newBook.write((char*)&bk,sizeof(Book))` -- This is not correct.  You are passing an address of a pointer to bk, not a pointer to bk.